# Is there an onmousedown event on iOS web applications?

Tags: javascript, iphone

I am trying to execute a function many times as long as the user is holding its finger down. How can I create an onmousedown event on an iOS device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for onTouchStart() event?

You could do something with jQuery mobile:
http://jquerymobile.com/test/#docs/api/events.html

taphold